# Evenly distribute 2 different values inside an array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of 2 different values and they need to be distributed evenly.

For example:

```
array = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

and the result I want is:

```
array = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

But also if the ratio is not 1:1 it should be distributed as evenly as possible:

```
array = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
result = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2]
```

or

```
array = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
result = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

What would be the best way to get this working?

I have tried the following, but it only works for my first example:

```
evenDistribute(array1, array2) {
            const longest = array1.length > array2.length ? array1 : array2;
            const shortest = array1.length > array2.length ? array2 : array1;
            const ratio = Math.floor(longest.length / shortest.length);
            const results = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < shortest.length; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < ratio; j++) {
                    results.push(longest[i * ratio + j]);
                }
                results.push(shortest[i]);
            }

            // Grab any that are left over
            for (let i = longest.length - (longest.length % shortest.length); i < longest.length; i++) {
                results.push(longest[i]);
            }
            return results;
        }
```

Comment: interesting question. do you hgave tried something? why is the last not immediately right?

Comment: _"What would be the best way to get this working?"_ I'm not sure if this is really the best way but I'd recommend to write a function that takes an array as argument and returns an array as output. You could separate the values into two arrays and use a merge algorithm.

Comment: Do you want to know why your solution doesn't work or what's the best way?

Comment: I have added the function I tried so far to my post above....
But it only works for example #1.

For example #2 it resulted in this:
`result = [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

So I'd need a way, that the value of which there are less to be distributed from the middle. But I have no idea how to do that...

Comment: Why is `[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2]` better than `[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]`?

Comment: do you have only two different values?

Comment: That does not really matter. Both results would be good for me. 
If it is almost evenly distributed that good enough because the final sorting will be done manually anyways

Comment: Yes it is only two types of luminaires. 
So for example i have 10 luminaires of type X and and 5 of Type Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this recursive version?

```js
// xs has the smaller length
const _evenDist = (xs, ys, count = Math .round (ys.length / (xs.length + 1))) => 
  xs .length == 0
    ? [... ys]
    : [... ys .slice (0, count), xs[0], ..._evenDist (xs .slice (1), ys .slice (count))] 

const evenDist = (xs, ys) =>
  xs .length > ys.length ? _evenDist(ys, xs) : _evenDist(xs, ys)

console .log (evenDist ([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2]) .join (' '))
console .log (evenDist ([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]) .join (' '))
console .log (evenDist ([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2]) .join (' '))

const letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' .split ('')
const digits = '0123456789' .split ('')
console .log (evenDist (letters, digits) .join (' '))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Assuming the `2`'s are in the larger list, we count how many `2`'s should appear before the first `1`, return an array with that many `2`, followed by a `1`, followed by a recursive call with that many fewer `2`'s and one fewer `1`.  The recursion bottoms out when there are no more `1`s, and we return the remaining `2`s.

We calculate the number of initial `2`s by thinking of the holes left with only the `1`s in them.  Since there are fewer `1`s there will be one hole before the first, one hole after the last, and one hole between every two consecutive `1`s.  That makes `n + 1` holes, where `n` is the number of `1`s.  Then we divide the number of `2`s by this value, and round it to the nearest integer.  We could equally well use `Math.ceil` or `Math.floor` instead of `Math.round`.  Those would put all the longer runs of `2`s to one end or the other.  `round` distributes them more evenly, and seems slightly better to me.

Note that this technique knows nothing about the contents of the two arrays, and in the example you can see it interspersing the letters and the digits into a single array.

### Addendum

The answer from Ben Stephens prompted me to think about how this could be extended to handle the dispersal of multiple different sets, not just two.  I found two approaches I like.

The first one is incomplete, and I probably won't bother to complete it, because the other one below seems good enough and is more in keeping with the answer above.  It is based on the [Huntington-Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntington%E2%80%93Hill_method) method used to apportion the seats in the US House of Representatives.  Although used elsewhere, mostly what it does is to divide the 435 House seats among the 50 states.  But it has the nice property that "If the number of seats was equal in size to the number of votes cast, this method would guarantee that the apportionments would equal the vote shares of each party."  I adapted [an implementation](https://gist.github.com/CrossEye/5a7ee1dd6e91f3cc0f4a12eca8128b88#file-source-js) of this method I wrote some time ago, tracking the *positions* of the next selections alongside their count.  (There was an ugly workaround where I started with a dummy element in each set to match the US apportionment requirement that every state get at least one vote.  Those were removed at the end.)  It's not complete, but it seems as though it would work.  You can see [my progress](http://link.sauyet.com/14) if you like, but I won't include it here.

The other version uses the above and adds a `disperse` function which takes an array of arrays and separates out the longest one, recursively calling itself on the remaining ones and then calling `evenDist` on that long one and those results.  And of course the recursion bottoms out when there are two or fewer arrays left.  I don't know if there's any notion of a perfect result for this problem, but these seem fairly good.

```js
// xs has the smaller length
const _evenDist = (xs, ys, count = Math .round (ys.length / (xs.length + 1))) => 
  xs .length == 0
    ? [... ys]
    : [... ys .slice (0, count), xs[0], ..._evenDist (xs .slice (1), ys .slice (count))] 

const evenDist = (xs, ys) =>
  xs .length > ys.length ? _evenDist(ys, xs) : _evenDist(xs, ys)

const findLongest = (
  xss, 
  max = Math .max (... xss .map (xs => xs .length)), 
  i = xss .findIndex (x => x .length == max)
) =>
  [xss [i], [... xss .slice (0, i), ... xss .slice (i + 1)]]

const disperse = (xss) =>
  xss .length < 2
    ? [... (xss [0] || [])]
    : (([ys, yss]) => evenDist (ys, disperse (yss))) (findLongest (xss))

console .log (disperse (['aaaaaaaa', 'bbb', 'cc']).join(' '))
console .log (disperse (['aaaaaaaa', '-----']).join(' '))
console .log (disperse (['@@@@@@@@', '-----', 'oooooo']).join(' '))
console .log (disperse (['@'.repeat(26), '.'.repeat(10), 'o'.repeat(14)]) .join (' '))
console .log (disperse (['@'.repeat(26), '-'.repeat(24)]) .join (' '))
const letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
const digits = '0123456789'
const dashes = '--------------'
const dots = '....'
console .log (disperse ([digits, dashes]) .join (' '))
console .log (disperse ([letters, digits, dashes]) .join (' '))
console .log (disperse ([letters, digits, dashes, dots]) .join (' '))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if this helps

```js
A = '.'
B = '@'

countA = 7
countB = 3


total = countA + countB
groupSize = Math.floor(total / countB)
numGroups = Math.floor(total / groupSize)
halfSize = (groupSize - 1) >> 1
group = A.repeat(halfSize) + B + A.repeat(halfSize)
result = group.repeat(numGroups) + A.repeat(total - group.length * numGroups)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: We should note that this requires `countA` to be larger than `countB`.  While `7/3` properly yields `.@..@..@..`, `3/7` yields `@@@@@@@@@@` and `7/7` yields `@@@@@@@.......`.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't quite do what you want, and has the downside of treating `'2'` and `2` in the same way (due to using object keys as part of the process) but I was wondering if it might be useful in some way:

```js
const disperse = (start) => {
  const counts = start.reduce((acc, value) => Object.assign(acc, { [value + '']: (acc[value + ''] || 0) + 1}), {});

  const weights = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(counts).map(([value, count]) => ([value, 1 / count]))
  );

  let usage_val = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(counts).map(([value, count]) => ([value, 0]))
  );

  let usage = { ...usage_val };

  const compare_weight = (key) => usage_val[key] + (weights[key] / 2);

  let result = [];

  for(let i = 0, next = null; i < start.length; i++) {
    Object.keys(counts).reverse().forEach((key) => {
      if(usage[key] === counts[key])
        return;
      if(next === null || compare_weight(key) <= compare_weight(next))
        next = key;      
    });

    result.push(next);
    usage[next] += 1;
    usage_val[next] += weights[next];
  }
  
  return result;
};


console.log(disperse([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]).join(' '));
console.log(disperse([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]).join(' '));
console.log(disperse([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]).join(' '));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: I love that this deals with multiple different values, not just 2, and you could easily fix the `2/'2'` issue by making `counts` a Map instead of an object.  But this result seems too far from what's desired: `1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1`.  I would think one requirement would be that every group of consecutive `1`'s differs in length from every other such group by no more than one.  Here you have one then three, then two, then one again.  I'm not certain, but I think this might be fixed in `weights` by dividing by `(count + 1)` instead of `count`.

Comment: I don't think that fix would do it.  Even with that in place, `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3` becomes `1 2 3 1 1 2 3 1 1 2 3 1 1`, when a clearly better dispersal would be `1 2 1 3 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 3 1`.  I'm curious to see if this can be patched.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @ScottSauyet , I'm hoping to come back to this when my brain is feeling a bit less smooth.